# Serial port reading using Command Prompt BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to communicate with a hardware through a TTL bridge via serial com port of a PC. And I found out some useful commands that help receiving and sending strings using a batch file . And here is my batch code

```
@echo off

mode COM3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8

:main

set /p x=5 <nul >\\.\COM3
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
type com3

goto main
```

The problem is that the batch file stucks when it arrives to "type com3" line . It starts to listen the com3 port and never leaves that line and stucks there .. Is there anything like a timeout procedure that will help to terminate the "type com3" line after a while ?

I'm not good at batch programming , all I can do is writing simple scripts using batch commands.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is CMD/batch really the only option you have?

Comment: For now : yes , what else would you suggest ?

Comment: I would suggest any programming language that has the power to deal with binary data. This would include almost anything except batch. Powershell and VBScript are two nearly-native options on Windows. Perl and Python would require you to install them, but they're both eminently flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

The `type com3` command will never return for you. It will listen on the port forever. A slight tweak to have 2 windows should help you out.

```
@echo off

mode COM3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8

start type com3

:main

set /p x=5 <nul >\\.\COM3
ping localhost -n 2 >nul

goto main
```

Comment: Well , an another question is how can I send decimal 5 instead of sending ascii 5 using batch ?